# Android XML Layout Error

Tags: android, html

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"   
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

</RelativeLayout>


?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/button_send" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[2013-08-03 09:55:43 - BrendansApp] Error in an XML file: aborting build.

Hello

I have been stuck on this same error for the last two days and nothing I try and do fixes it!
Any ideas on how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think if this question qualify to be in SO

Answer (score 0):

use `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` you are missing `<` in `?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

and also it **should be first line in your xml code**

```
and also you have two root elements in xml.. there should be single root element
```

so your code should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/button_send" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `so your code should be` hehe two root elements in xml... Good luck :-)